# Function Delegates with Parameters c#

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-delegates

I'm looking for way to call Methods with Parameters using a Function Delegate.

You could  use the function delegate in the place instead of calling processOperationB. but looking for any way that the below way can be achieved.

```
public class Client
{

    public AOutput OperationA (string param1, string param2)
    {
    //Some Operation 
    }

    public BOutput  OperationB(string param1, string param2)
    {
        //Some Operation 
    }
}


public class Manager 
{
    private Client cl;



    public Manager()
    {
        cl=new Client();
    }


    private void processOperationA(string param1, string param2)
    {

        var res = cl.OperationA(param1,param2); 
        //...   

    }

    private void processOperationB(string param1, string param2)
    {
        var res = cl.OperationB(param1,param2); 

        // trying to Call using the GetData , in that case I could get rid of individual menthods for processOperationA, processOperationB

        var res= GetData<BOutput>( x=> x.OperationB(param1,param2));
    }


    // It could have been done using Action, but it should return a value 
    private T GetData<T>(Func<Client,T> delegateMethod)
    {

    // how a Function delegate with params can be invoked 
    // Compiler expects the arguments to be passed here. But have already passed all params .

        delegateMethod();


    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem with that code? Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do... Why would be the purpose of calling `GetData` as you can directly execute the code...

Answer (score 2):

Your comment reads:

> Compiler expects the arguments to be passed here

But that's not really true. Yes, it expects an argument, but not what you think it expects.

Your `delegateMethod` parameter is a `Func<Client, T>`, which means it requires a single argument, of type `Client`, and returns a value of type `T`. Based on the code you've shown, you should write this instead:

```
private T GetData<T>(Func<Client,T> delegateMethod)
{
    return delegateMethod(cl);
}
```

It is not clear to me what broader problem you're trying to solve is. I don't see the `GetData<T>()` method adding anything here; the callers could just call the appropriate *"Operation..."* method in each case, I'd think (i.e. as in your `processOperationA()` method).

But at least we can solve the compiler error. If you'd like help with that broader problem, you can post a new question. Make sure to include a good [Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to do, and explain precisely what you've tried and what's not working.